# How to implement a function that will take a list of strings and parse them into a list of tuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new function that runs a list of string measurements through a parsing function `parse_measurement` and returns a list of tuple values. For example if I enter `parse_measurement(["1 ft", "8 ft", "3.3 meters"])` I would want to return `[(1, 'ft'), (8, 'ft'), (3.3, 'meters')]`.

This is my parse_measurement function. It will parse a single string into a tuple. i.e. `"3 ft"` outputs to `('3', 'ft')`.

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value: str):
    tuple_value = tuple(measure_value.split(' '))
    return tuple_value
```

Goal Output:
`[(1, 'ft'), (8, 'ft'), (3.3, 'meters')]`

Comment: Your function _almost_ does what you want for one string -- remember to convert the first item from `.split(' ')` to a `float`. Then, call this function once for each string in your list. I suggest you redo a tutorial on looping and lists if you get stuck with this.

Comment: It's unclear what your *question* is. You have a function that produces something close to what you want, and you know what you want. What exactly is preventing you from doing the rest of the task? What is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: Your asking two questions at once. "how do i apply parse_measurement on a list" and "how do i parse str objects to numbers". please edit your question to only ask 1 question.

Comment: @steviestickman both those questions already have answers, so they'd be closed as dupes anyway.

Comment: It's unclear why people are so unhelpful, although try doing: `mytuple = tuple((float(tuple_value[0]), str(tuple_value[1])))` then `return mytuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear on what you really want, so I'm assuming this is the actual problem. Starting from the statement in which you said that you needed something that looks like this : `parse_measurement(["1 ft", "8 ft", "3.3 meters"])`, and following up on it :

In the following code :

- I take the list of strings
- loop over each str measurment
- Separate and *parse* the values as needed
- Append the results as a tuple into the final list.
- And finally return the final_list

```
def parse_measurement(measure_values: list):
    final_list = []
    for m_value in measure_values:
        measure, unit = m_value.split()
        measure = float(measure)
        final_list.append((measure, unit))
    return final_list


print( parse_measurement(["1 ft", "8 ft", "3.3 meters"]) )
# [(1.0, 'ft'), (8.0, 'ft'), (3.3, 'meters')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def parse_measurement(measure_value: str):
    value, units = tuple(measure_value.split(' '))
    return (float(value), units)
```

Comment: I was kinda looking forward to your regex answer. Mind though: regex to just split on whitespace and convert the first element to a float seems like _massive_ overkill.

Comment: i misunderstood the question, i think that `"[(1, 'ft'), (8, 'ft'), (3.3, 'meters')]"` is input where as input is  `["1 ft", "8 ft", "3.3 meters"]` sorry for that.